# cambiar el tipo de dato en Python

Tags: python, int, str

Tengo un fichero de texto llamado `datos.txt` con valores numéricos, así:

```
2
5
1
```

Lo leo con el siguiente código:

```
datos = []
with open ("datos.txt") as fichero:
    for dato in fichero.read():
        datos.append(dato)
```

Esto lee cada línea como una cadena. Después intento convertir cada elemento de la lista datos a numérico, así:

```
for dato in datos:
    numero = int(dato)
    print (numero)
```

Esto debería funcionar, pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2\n3'
```

¿Por qué se produce ese error? ¿Cómo puedo convertir esos datos que son `str` a `int`?
Estoy usando el IDLE de Python 3

Comment: Ahí pone en el error que está cogiendo un 2, un salto de línea y un 3 seguidamente. Ese  es el txt completo de 2,5,1?

Comment: Cuando hagas el bucle for dato in fichero.read(): haz un print(dato), y mira a ver que te trae. Y editas la pregunta para qure lo veamos

Comment: No uses `read`, en cambio usa [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). Saludos

Comment: Generalmente, la mejor opcion para obtener cada linea de un txt de la forma mas comoda y sin cargarlo entero en memoria, es iterar sobre el objeto que representa el archivo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema es que `fichero.read()` lee el fichero completo en una sola cadena de texto. Por ello cuando haces `for dato in fichero.read()` estarás iterando por esa cadena.

El iterar por una cadena hace que la proceses de caracter en caracter. Eso es en general incorrecto. Imagina que en una línea tienes el dato "25". Al procesarlo caracter a caracter lo estarías considerando como dos datos,el "2" y el "5". Además tienes el problema de que ciertos caracteres no son dígitos, sino los finales de línea (`\n`). Una alternativa es la función `readlines()`. Esta función devuelve una lista de cadenas, cada una de ellas correspondiente a una línea del fichero.

De ese modo cada iteración del bucle te devuelve una línea completa (de la que ha eliminado el `\n` del final). Esa lína ya contendrá uno de los datos que podrás convertir en `int`.

Puedes aprovechar para convertir a entero ya directamente en cada iteración. De ese modo la lista `datos` ya será de enteros en vez de cadenas.

```
datos = []
with open ("datos.txt") as fichero:
    for dato in fichero.readlines():
        datos.append(int(dato))
```

### Formas más "pythónicas"

La propia variable `fichero` es iterable en Python, y en cada iteración te devuelve una línea, por lo que podríamos poner directamente:

```
datos = []
with open ("datos.txt") as fichero:
    for dato in fichero:
        datos.append(int(dato))
```

Esto es preferible al uso de `readlines()` ya que la lista de líneas creada por `readlines()` estará ocupando memoria (más cuanto mayor sea el fichero leído). En cambio iterar por el fichero lee las lineas de una en una sin guardarlas en lista alguna.

Usando comprensión de listas el código anterior se puede reducir un poco más:

```
with open ("datos.txt") as fichero:
  datos = [int(dato) for dato in fichero]
```